# Set Label content and make it disappear after 5 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, wpf, async-await

Let's say I have a label and a button. If I click the button, the label is set to some text, say "hello, world!", and after 5 seconds, it should disappear. Easy enough, right? I have the following implementation:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  await Task.Delay(5_000);
  Label = string.Empty;
}
```

Now let's say I have the additional requirement that the button should remain responsive on each subsequent button click, and now the label text should remain `hello, world!` for the next 5 seconds i.e. the label text should remain for 5 seconds since the last time the button was clicked. The problem with the previous code is that if I had clicked the button 2.5 seconds ago and click it again now, the label text will disappear after 2.5 seconds. My idea to solve this was to maintain a list of tasks and add the delay task and await the task list before clearing the label. This is the implementation:

```
private static readonly List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  TaskList.Add(Task.Delay(5_000));      
  await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
  if (TaskList.TrueForAll(t => t.IsCompleted))
  {
    TaskList.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
    Label = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Implementation with a cancellation token:

```
private static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
  _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  try
  {
    await Task.Delay(5_000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    Label = string.Empty;
  } catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
}
```

As far as I know, these implementation works, but I don't know much about asynchronous programming so I don't know how to be *absolutely sure* it works.

**Questions**:
How would you implement this? Is there a better way to implement this? I originally figured that `Task.WhenAll()` would take care of waiting for all tasks to complete, but this does not seem to be the case. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: This looks very much like pseudocode. Can you post your real solution?

Comment: Did you think about a timer instead of tasks?

Comment: @t3chb0t It's not. This is the actual source code.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You have `Label = "hello, world!";` in your actual source? Why?

Comment: @Mast This code lives in a toy project that I'm using to learn more about asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a timer.

On callback, you set the content of your label to empty. You just have to restart the timer on every button click.

I think it simplifies a lot the code.

Comment: I added an implementation using your ideas at the bottom. Can you please comment? Thanks.

Comment: @asfeynman: thanks for sharing your improved solution. If you want to discuss it, it is better to post it as new question (follow up).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation suggested by @ogomrun using the timer class:

```
private Timer timer;
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  if (timer == null)
  {
    timer = new Timer(state => Label = string.Empty, null, 5_000, Timeout.Infinite);
  }
  else
  {
    timer.Change(5_000, Timeout.Infinite);
  }
}
```